# code optimization - I want to retrieve a available group where a member does not already exist

Tags: php, performance, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are three tables:

```
user,member,group_member(relation mem_id,group_id) many to many
```

I have defined a relation for a group on member model

```
public function group(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Model\Group', 'group_member', 'mem_id', 'group_id');
    }
```

using the above relation I can retrieve a member assigned to a group using

```
   Model\Member::with('group')->find('member_id')
```

now I want those groups where the member is not assigned.

I am able to do this using

```
$arg['ids'] = $member->group->lists('_id');
        $group = Group::where('user_id',$user_id)->whereNotIn('_id',$arg['ids'])->limit($arg['limit'])->offset($arg['offset'])->get();
```

Is there another option rather than using a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only retrieve groups **related** to **Member** object with its relations. In order to get all unrelated groups, you'll need to run a query on **Group** model.

The following code should do the trick:

```
$unrelatedGroups = Group::whereDoesnHave('member', function($query) use ($user_id) {
  $query->where('id', $user_id);
})->get();
```

This will return all groups that don't have a member with given **$user_id**. Just make sure you have a many-to-many relation defined in your **Group** model called **member** that links to all members of given group.